# <Selenium>Customize cucumber reporting with addition of Graphs (In addition to default graph)

Tags: selenium, karate

I wanted to add graph to exisitng cucumber reporting ( apart from the default one it shows). Can some one help?

Requirement is as below:
I am working on a home loan processing application.
Once the automation test cases are executed, I need to generate a graph of correlation between loan submitted per second and loan processing time.

Note: I am using karate framework for this.
However any solution / logic will be appreciated.

Comment: sorry if you want to customize anything, write your own report. all the data is available in the `Results` object